# LXD command is executed on host instead of container

Tags: command-line, bash, lxc, mssql

I am using this command: `lxc exec container -- sh -c 'sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P <..> -i <...>'`, but it will get executed on the host instead of the container.

But when I `lxc shell container` and then run `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P <..> -i <...>`, the command works fine.

What is happening here and why isn't it executing in the container? I am using other commands like `lxc exec container -- touch testfile`, that do not raise any issues.

Comment: Please file a bug report with LXD (https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues) for this issue. The LXD developers did not intend that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured that instead of using `sqlcmd` I would have to use the full path of the command. The command did execute in the container, but although I could run the command inside the container, the command could not be found when executed from outside. I misinterpreted the error message to be executed on the host, which was not correct. I guess this depends on how the path to sqlcmd is set.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `lxc exec mycontainer -- somecommand`, then the *somecommand* (whatever is found after the `--`) runs in the container.

As a rule of thumb, if a complex command appears to behave weirdly, then you should simplify it as much as possible. Why would this long SQL command run on the host and not some other shorter command?

Most likely you have used backticks instead of single quotes for that SQL command. When you run a command and there are backticks, those backticks are interpreted first and whatever is found between them, does indeed run on the host. The output of that command is then placed on the command line in the place of that backtick command.

Comment: I did not use backticks. Why should I? The code line above is copy-pasted with sensitive data removed.

Comment: If the command was `sh -c 'hostname'`, would it still show the hostname of the host? I mean, can you simplify the command to some common command?